# パレットのテキストボックスのコピペができない

Tags: .net, ijcad

Paltte上にTextBoxとCombobox、DataGridViewを配置して情報入力用パレットを作成しました。
Comboboxでは、文字列を選択してCtrl+C、Ctrl+Vで文字列のコピペができるのですが、TextBoxとDataGridViewのセルでは図面内のエンティティへの操作となってしまいます。
Comboboxと同様に文字列のコピペを有効にする方法をご教示いただけると助かります。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

現在リリースされている最新のIJCADでは、問題なくTextBoxやDataGridViewのセルの内容をCtrl+Cでコピーできましたので、使用しているIJCADが古いバージョンであればアップグレードしてみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
IJCAD2019にて確認しましたが、現象は変わりませんでした。
パレットのKeepFocusプロパティ以外に設定が必要なのでしょうか。